# Changing style dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic

My navigation looks like this:

```
    <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutSP.html">Expertise</a></li>
      <li><a href="hcwh.html">Help</a> </li>
      <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

JQuery to dynamically change the colour of the menu item for the page selected is:

```
$('#nav li a').each(function(){
       var path = window.location.href;
       var current = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
       var menu_item = $(this).attr('href');
       if(menu_item == current){
          $(this).addClass('active');
       };
    });
```

CSS looks like this:

```
 ul#nav li a.active {
   color: #009CDE;
   text-shadow: none;
 }

 .active {
   color: #009CDE;
   text-shadow: none;
 }
```

My question: I need the first style so that the jQuery will work locally but I need the second style so that the jQuery will work from the server. Why is this so?
Thanks

Comment: I believe you have a browser caching problem. When you run the page online it's not updating the changes in your CSS file. Clear your browser's cache and try again. (This is only an assumption, as there's no reason for the first not to work online).

Comment: Trivial, but you have a semicolon after the closing bracket of your if.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa I don't think an extra semicolon there is a problem. It would only be bad if he tried to add an `else` clause.

Comment: @Barmar. Of course it isn't. That's why it was a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: @BassemDy Seems answer worthy :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you face discrepancies between your local page rendering and online version the first step of troubleshooting the problem is to make sure it's not a **browser caching issue**.

Clear your browsers' cache and try again.

**Preventive measures:**

You can prevent this problem during development and staging by versioning your CSS file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css?v=1">`

When you introduce new changes and wish to push them online, you change your version number `?v=2`. This guarantees your browser is always requesting the CSS file and not grabbing the cache stored version.

Comment: Or disable cache all together. +1